# Get current value on sliderstop and set cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cookies, jquery-ui-slider

I'm using jQuery UI slider to set css opactiy, followed the api docs on how to get the value but when I test it it's not changing the opacity value of the element.

EDIT: Everything is now working (sending value and setting cookie), I've updated the code below if it's any help to anybody, thanks for your input guys!

HTML:

```
<h5>Header Opacity</h5>

<div id="op-slider-header"></div>
<input id="headerOpVal" type="hidden" />

<script type="text/javascript">
// header opacity 
$(function() {

    if ($.cookie('headOp')==null){
        $.cookie('headOp',0.5);

    }
    $('.row.header .bg').css('opacity', $.cookie('headOp'));

    $( "#op-slider-header" ).slider({
        max: 1,
        min: 0,
        value: $.cookie('headOp'),
        step:0.1,
        slide: function(e,ui) {

          $.cookie('headOp',ui.value);
         $('#headerOpVal').html(ui.value);
        }
    });


    $( "#op-slider-header" ).on( "slidestop", function( event, ui ) {
        var val = $('#headerOpVal').html(ui.value);
        $('.row.header .bg').css('opacity', ui.value);
        $.cookie("headOp", ui.value, { expires: 7});
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: do you get any console error with current implementation?

Comment: no, but the element gets highlighted when I change the slider so the code must be processing to that point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to ensure that you are setting the opacity to an integer. Try this:

```
var val = parseFloat(ui.value, 10);
```

Shouldn't `ui` variable in your slidestop event listener contain the slide value?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, it should have been `parseFloat` as the opacity would be returned as a decimal, not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `$('#headerOpVal').attr("value", ui.value);` to store value instead of html.

And usign `$('#headerOpVal').attr("value");` to retrive that value.

But it's hard to say wich is the problem, try to post the html too.

Comment: This doesn't work either, I'm not sure it's getting the value? or at least it's not updating the css inline

Comment: try to log the ui.value in the 'on( "slidestop" , ...)' function with the following code: `console.log(ui.value)`

Comment: use `ui.value` instead of `val` when you set the opacity  `$('.row.header').css('opacity', ui.value);`

Comment: Perfect! is now working Thank You! - just need to sort the cookie out cos it's not saving :/